# Probability of winning golf match

Tags: probability

Golfers A. B, and C are all of equal ability. Each has a 50% chance of beating the other in a heads-up match. If they all three play a match simultaneously, then what is the probability each one wins the match? Logically, it has to be 33.3%, but I can’t figure out how to show this mathematically.
Thanks
Burt

Comment: This is not clear.  First of all, we have no information on the three way matchups.  But even if you assume that each player acts independently of all others (in any combination), then you have to explain how ties are resolved.

Comment: All that said, if, say, you declare that ties are resolved on a coin toss, then symmetry does indicate that each player has an equal chance of winning and, since the three probabilities would, under this assumption, sum to $1$, they much all be $\frac 13$.

Comment: As lulu eluded, if the players do not act independently of all others, then this problem is not at all clear. For example, suppose player $A$ cheats half the time and plays fairly the other half the time. If player $A$ cheats, he always wins, but if he plays fairly, he always loses. This means, there is a $50\%$ chance that $A$ will win regardless of how many opponents there are. The remaining opponents's win chances must add up to $50\%$.

Comment: As already pointed out, you need to specify how the 1v1 rules translate to a game with 3 players. Without that, there is no clear answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "equal ability"? Is that just another way of saying that in head-to-head competition each pair splits their matches equally; or does it mean that their golf scores come from identical probability distributions?  And if they do come from identical distributions, are they independent?

Comment: Yes, equal ability means A would beat B half the time and B would beat A half the time in a head-to-head match.There are never any ties. And the same assumptions for the other match-ups. Also, it seems that independence is a plausible assumption. If A beats B, then that doesn’t give any info as to whether A beats C or not. A naive analysis then implies the prob that A wins the match = prob A beats B and prob A beats C = .5x.5 = .25. What’s wrong with this?

Comment: In a 3-way match, the head-to-heads are never completely independent. For example, true independence would allow for the following: $A$ beats $B$, $B$ beats $C$, and $C$ beats $A$. This is utterly impossible in a golf game, implying that in the 3-way match, the individual head-to-head matches are not independent.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a scenario that shows that they are not necessarily equally likely to win a three-way match.

A always shoots a 70 or a 75 with equal probability.

B always shoots a 71 or a 74 with equal probability.

C always shoots a 72 or 73 with equal probability.

Arguably this means the golfers are of equal ability (each averaging 72.5 shots per round).

Assume that in matches, which of the two possible scores each golfer gets is independent of what the other golfers get.  Then golfer A will win half the 3-way matches (whenever golfer A shoots a 70, golfer A wins the 3-way match).

Comment: Thanks for comments and example. Your example begs the question” is it easy to come up with an example which, in, fact , would give each golfer a 1/3 chance of winning the match?”

Comment: Yes, you could likely come up with $\frac13$ each examples. However, in the original post, it was asserted that "logically it [probability of each golfer winning] must be 33.3%".  This example shows that this need not be the case.